# I have issues about panels in wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, panel, boxsizer

I want to do a interface with wxpython like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2695O.png)
I have  issues about embeding webview, button, textview and plots in different panels

and when I tried to embed a webview in panel3 it shown like little square on top right of the panel

please help me

```
import wx
import wx.html2 

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title)
        
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        
        panel1 = wx.Panel(self,-1 , pos=(1,1),size=(1600,50), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self,-1 , pos=(1,50),size=(1300,500), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        panel3 = wx.Panel(self,-1 , pos=(1300,50),size=(300,500), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        panel4 = wx.Panel(self,-1 , pos=(1,550),size=(1600,500), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        

        panel1.SetBackgroundColour("BLUE")    #buttons in here
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour("RED")     #plots in here
        panel3.SetBackgroundColour("GREY")    #webview in here
        panel4.SetBackgroundColour("YELLOW")  #textview in here
        
        browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(panel3)
        browser.LoadURL("http://www.google.com")
        hbox.Add(browser,wx.EXPAND)
     
         

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "Sizer Test")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a `Sizer` but you haven't assigned it, with `SetSizer`.
I assume, in an attempt to force it to work, you have included postions for the panels. A `Sizer` removes the need to have positions, as the `Sizer`/`Sizers` perform that task for you.
If we remove the positions, assign some rational sizes and apply the `Sizers`, we get this.
It may not be what you are striving for but it's a starting point.

```
import wx
import wx.html2 

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title)
        
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        panel1 = wx.Panel(self,-1 , size=(-1,100), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self,-1 , size=(-1,100), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        panel3 = wx.Panel(self,-1 , size=(-1,400), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        panel4 = wx.Panel(self,-1 , size=(-1,100), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        

        panel1.SetBackgroundColour("BLUE")    #buttons in here
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour("RED")     #plots in here
        panel3.SetBackgroundColour("GREY")    #webview in here
        panel4.SetBackgroundColour("YELLOW")  #textview in here
        
        browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(panel3)
        browser.LoadURL("http://www.duckduckgo.com")

        hbox.Add(browser, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        panel3.SetSizer(hbox)

        vbox.Add(panel1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add(panel2, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add(panel3, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add(panel4, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)     
         

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "Sizer Test")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help, i did this with many boxsizer hahah